# How to make an image and display it on the next page

Tags: android, python-3.x, kivy, android-camera, kivy-language

Good afternoon, i wrote a simple camera program using Python and Kivy, but I just can't get a shot. You need to take a snapshot of "ScreenThree" (save it in the phone's memory) and display the resulting image on "ScreenFour".

I use kivy.uix.camera to display the camera, kivymd and kv to create the interface. 
android.permissions:INTERNET,CAMERA,WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.camera import Camera
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager

import time

Builder.load_string("""
#:import MDFillRoundFlatButton kivymd.button.MDFillRoundFlatButton
#:import MDIconButton kivymd.button.MDIconButton
<ScreenOne@Screen>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: [.30,.50,.99]
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    FloatLayout:
        MDFillRoundFlatButton:
            color: [1,1,1,1]
            text: "Перейти к созданию фото"
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.50, 'center_y':.50}
            on_press:
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'up'
                root.manager.transition.duration = 1
                root.manager.current = 'screen_two'

<ScreenTwo@Screen>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: [.30,.50,.99]
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    FloatLayout:
        MDFillRoundFlatButton:
            color: [1,1,1,1]
            text: "Выбрать фон"
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.50, 'center_y':.10}
            on_press:
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'up'
                root.manager.transition.duration = 1
                root.manager.current = 'screen_three'
        MDIconButton:
            icon: 'chevron-double-right'
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.95, 'center_y':.10}
            on_press:
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'down'
                root.manager.transition.duration = 1
                root.manager.current = 'screen_one'

<ScreenThree@Screen>:
    id: entry
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: [.30,.50,.99]
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    FloatLayout:
        Camera:
            id: camera
            index: 0
            resolution: (1280,720)
            play: True  
        MDFillRoundFlatButton:
            text: "take photo"
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.50, 'center_y': .10}
            on_press:
                root.capture()   #TAKE PHOTO
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'up'
                root.manager.transition.duration = 1
                root.manager.current = 'screen_four'    
        MDIconButton:
            icon: 'chevron-double-right'
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.95, 'center_y':.10}
            on_press:
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'down'
                root.manager.transition.duration = 1
                root.manager.current = 'screen_two'

<ScreenFour@Screen>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: [.30,.50,.99]
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    FloatLayout:
# HERE I NEED TO DISPLAY THE IMAGE
        MDIconButton:
            icon: 'chevron-double-right'
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.95, 'center_y':.10}
            on_press:
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'down'
                root.manager.transition.duration = 1
                root.manager.current = 'screen_three'
""")


class ScreenOne(Screen):
    pass


class ScreenTwo(Screen):
    theme_cls = ThemeManager()
    theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Blue'
    main_widget = None

class ScreenThree(Screen):
    theme_cls = ThemeManager()
    theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Blue'
    main_widget = None

    def capture(self):
        camera = self.ids['camera']
        timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
        photo = camera.export_to_png("IMG_{}.png".format(timestr))
        print("Captured")



class ScreenFour(Screen):
    pass


screen_manager = ScreenManager()


screen_manager.add_widget(ScreenOne(name="screen_one"))
screen_manager.add_widget(ScreenTwo(name="screen_two"))
screen_manager.add_widget(ScreenThree(name="screen_three"))
screen_manager.add_widget(ScreenFour(name="screen_four"))


class Interface(App):

    def build(self):
        return screen_manager

sample_app = Interface()
sample_app.run()
```

Tell me, please, how can I modify the code to complete the task.

### Error

[Take photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7d1dB.jpg)
[White screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMlmK.jpg)

```
04-08 21:15:19.925   796 13801 E mm-camera: <STATS_AF ><ERROR> 959: af_spd_detect_process: ERROR! SPOT_LIGHT_FLAG =0!!! :AEC_grid = 256, BG_grid = 3072, ave luma = 0
04-08 21:15:19.933   835   902 W SurfaceFlinger: EventThread: dropping event (7673796e) for connection 0x7b332278c0
04-08 21:15:19.949   835   902 W SurfaceFlinger: EventThread: dropping event (7673796e) for connection 0x7b332278c0
04-08 21:15:19.959   796 13801 E mm-camera: <STATS_AF ><ERROR> 959: af_spd_detect_process: ERROR! SPOT_LIGHT_FLAG =0!!! :AEC_grid = 256, BG_grid = 3072, ave luma = 0
04-08 21:15:19.966   835   902 W SurfaceFlinger: EventThread: dropping event (7673796e) for connection 0x7b332278c0
04-08 21:15:19.983   835   902 W SurfaceFlinger: EventThread: dropping event (7673796e) for connection 0x7b332278c0
04-08 21:15:19.992   796 13801 E mm-camera: <STATS_AF ><ERROR> 959: af_spd_detect_process: ERROR! SPOT_LIGHT_FLAG =0!!! :AEC_grid = 256, BG_grid = 3072, ave luma = 0
04-08 21:15:19.999   835   902 W SurfaceFlinger: EventThread: dropping event (7673796e) for connection 0x7b332278c0
```

### Error2

```
04-09 08:27:25.140   796  6243 E mm-camera: <STATS_AF ><ERROR> 959: af_spd_detect_process: ERROR! SPOT_LIGHT_FLAG =0!!! :AEC_grid = 256, BG_grid = 3072, ave luma = 0
04-09 08:27:25.146   835   902 W SurfaceFlinger: EventThread: dropping event (7673796e) for connection 0x7b32a54420
04-09 08:27:25.146  6164  6198 I python  : Captured
04-09 08:27:25.147  6164  6198 I python  : [ERROR  ] [Image       ] Error reading file IMG_20190409_082724.png
04-09 08:27:25.162   835   902 W SurfaceFlinger: EventThread: dropping event (7673796e) for connection 0x7b32a54420
04-09 08:27:25.175   796  6243 E mm-camera: <STATS_AF ><ERROR> 959: af_spd_detect_process: ERROR! SPOT_LIGHT_FLAG =0!!! :AEC_grid = 256, BG_grid = 3072, ave luma = 0
04-09 08:27:25.179   835   902 W SurfaceFlinger: EventThread: dropping event (7673796e) for connection 0x7b32a54420
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Access photo

Reference the photo using the following:

```
class ScreenFour(Screen):

    def on_pre_enter(self, *args):
        self.ids.img.source = self.manager.ids.entry.photo
```

## Solution

### Note

```
<class-name@widget>:
```

This is a [dynamic class](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#dynamic-classes). When using dynamic class, there is no need for class definition in Python script.

### kv file

- Change all dynamic classes to class rule by removing all `@Screen`.
- Add a class rule, `<ScreenManagement>:`
- Instantiate all the screens as child of class rule, `<ScreenManagement>:`
- Add `id: entry` under instantiated child, ScreenThree:
- Instantiate, `Image:` as child of `FloatLayout:` of class rule, `<ScreenFour>:`
- Add `id: img` under instantiated child, `Image:`

#### Snippets

```
#:import MDIconButton kivymd.button.MDIconButton

<ScreenManagement>:
    ScreenOne:
        name: "screen_one"
    ScreenTwo:
        name: "screen_two"
    ScreenThree:
        id: entry
        name: "screen_three"
    ScreenFour:
        name: "screen_four"
...

<ScreenFour>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: [.30,.50,.99]
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    FloatLayout:
        Image:
            id: img
```

### Py file

- Add import statement, `from os.path import dirname`
- Add import statement, `from kivy.properties import StringProperty`
- Add `class ScreenManagement()`
- Remove all references to `screen_manager`
- Declare class attribute, `photo = StringProperty('')` under `class ScreenThree()`
- Initialize class attribute, `self.photo = f"{dirname(__file__)}/IMG_{time.strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')}.png"`
- Implement method `on_pre_enter()` to display photo.

#### Snippets

```
from os.path import dirname
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
...
class ScreenThree(Screen):
    photo = StringProperty('')

    def capture(self):
        camera = self.ids['camera']
        self.photo = f"{dirname(__file__)}/IMG_{time.strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')}.png"
        camera.export_to_png(self.photo)
        print("Captured")


class ScreenFour(Screen):

    def on_pre_enter(self, *args):
        self.ids.img.source = self.manager.ids.entry.photo


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass


class Interface(App):

    def build(self):
        return ScreenManagement()
```

### Example

#### main.py

```
from os.path import dirname
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

import time

Builder.load_string("""
#:import MDFillRoundFlatButton kivymd.button.MDFillRoundFlatButton
#:import MDIconButton kivymd.button.MDIconButton

<ScreenManagement>:
    ScreenOne:
        name: "screen_one"
    ScreenTwo:
        name: "screen_two"
    ScreenThree:
        name: "screen_three"
        id: entry
    ScreenFour:
        name: "screen_four"

<ScreenOne>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: [.30,.50,.99]
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    FloatLayout:
        MDFillRoundFlatButton:
            color: [1,1,1,1]
            text: "Перейти к созданию фото"
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.50, 'center_y':.50}
            on_press:
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'up'
                root.manager.transition.duration = 1
                root.manager.current = 'screen_two'

<ScreenTwo>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: [.30,.50,.99]
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    FloatLayout:
        MDFillRoundFlatButton:
            color: [1,1,1,1]
            text: "Выбрать фон"
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.50, 'center_y':.10}
            on_press:
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'up'
                root.manager.transition.duration = 1
                root.manager.current = 'screen_three'
        MDIconButton:
            icon: 'chevron-double-right'
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.95, 'center_y':.10}
            on_press:
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'down'
                root.manager.transition.duration = 1
                root.manager.current = 'screen_one'

<ScreenThree>:
    id: entry
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: [.30,.50,.99]
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    FloatLayout:
        Camera:
            id: camera
            index: 0
            resolution: (1280,720)
            play: True  
        MDFillRoundFlatButton:
            text: "take photo"
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.50, 'center_y': .10}
            on_press:
                root.capture()   #TAKE PHOTO
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'up'
                root.manager.transition.duration = 1
                root.manager.current = 'screen_four'    
        MDIconButton:
            icon: 'chevron-double-right'
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.95, 'center_y':.10}
            on_press:
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'down'
                root.manager.transition.duration = 1
                root.manager.current = 'screen_two'

<ScreenFour>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: [.30,.50,.99]
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    FloatLayout:
        Image:
            id: img

        MDIconButton:
            icon: 'chevron-double-right'
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.95, 'center_y':.10}
            on_press:
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'down'
                root.manager.transition.duration = 1
                root.manager.current = 'screen_three'
""")


class ScreenOne(Screen):
    pass


class ScreenTwo(Screen):
    theme_cls = ThemeManager()
    theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Blue'
    main_widget = None


class ScreenThree(Screen):
    theme_cls = ThemeManager()
    theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Blue'
    main_widget = None
    photo = StringProperty('')

    def capture(self):
        camera = self.ids['camera']
        self.photo = f"{dirname(__file__)}/IMG_{time.strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')}.png"
        camera.export_to_png(self.photo)
        print("Captured")


class ScreenFour(Screen):

    def on_pre_enter(self, *args):
        self.ids.img.source = self.manager.ids.entry.photo


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass


class Interface(App):

    def build(self):
        return ScreenManagement()


sample_app = Interface()
sample_app.run()
```

## Output

[image: Photo]

Comment: Hi, the same problem, after the "take photo" white screen, how to fix it?

Comment: Add import statement, `from os.path import dirname` and prefix photo filename with `dirname(__file__)` e.g. `self.photo = f"{dirname(__file__)}/IMG_{time.strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')}.png"`

Comment: The error remained, still the white screen after clicking "take photo" and in the log: "python: [ERROR] [Image] Error reading file /IMG_20190409_192950.png"

Comment: Are you able to find and view that file on your phone using Gallery or Photos?

Comment: No, I tried to look for it, it is not displayed in the gallery, and I could not find the directory in which it is located.

Comment: Add a print statement into method `capture()` to show the location e.g. `print(f"self.photo={self.photo}")`

Comment: Here is the directory:"python: self.photo = / IMG_20190409_195718.png"

Comment: Perhaps a directory change to home will help? Only I can't do it.

Answer (score 2):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.camera import Camera
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager

import time

filename = ''
screenfour = ''

Builder.load_string("""
#:import MDFillRoundFlatButton kivymd.button.MDFillRoundFlatButton
#:import MDIconButton kivymd.button.MDIconButton
<ScreenOne@Screen>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: [.30,.50,.99]
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    FloatLayout:
        MDFillRoundFlatButton:
            color: [1,1,1,1]
            text: "Перейти к созданию фото"
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.50, 'center_y':.50}
            on_press:
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'up'
                root.manager.transition.duration = 1
                root.manager.current = 'screen_two'

<ScreenTwo@Screen>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: [.30,.50,.99]
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    FloatLayout:
        MDFillRoundFlatButton:
            color: [1,1,1,1]
            text: "Выбрать фон"
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.50, 'center_y':.10}
            on_press:
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'up'
                root.manager.transition.duration = 1
                root.manager.current = 'screen_three'
        MDIconButton:
            icon: 'chevron-double-right'
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.95, 'center_y':.10}
            on_press:
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'down'
                root.manager.transition.duration = 1
                root.manager.current = 'screen_one'

<ScreenThree@Screen>:
    id: entry
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: [.30,.50,.99]
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    FloatLayout:
        Camera:
            id: camera
            index: 0
            resolution: (1280,720)
            play: True
        MDFillRoundFlatButton:
            text: "take photo"
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.50, 'center_y': .10}
            on_press:
                root.capture()   #TAKE PHOTO
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'up'
                root.manager.transition.duration = 1
                root.manager.current = 'screen_four'
        MDIconButton:
            icon: 'chevron-double-right'
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.95, 'center_y':.10}
            on_press:
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'down'
                root.manager.transition.duration = 1
                root.manager.current = 'screen_two'

<ScreenFour@Screen>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: [.30,.50,.99]
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    FloatLayout:
        Image:
            size: root.width, root.height
            source: ''
            id: imageWid
        MDIconButton:
            icon: 'chevron-double-right'
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.95, 'center_y':.10}
            on_press:
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'down'
                root.manager.transition.duration = 1
                root.manager.current = 'screen_three'
""")


class ScreenOne(Screen):
    pass


class ScreenTwo(Screen):
    theme_cls = ThemeManager()
    theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Blue'
    main_widget = None

class ScreenThree(Screen):
    theme_cls = ThemeManager()
    theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Blue'
    main_widget = None

    def capture(self):
        camera = self.ids['camera']
        timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
        photo = camera.export_to_png("IMG_{}.png".format(timestr))
        global filename, screenfour
        filename = "IMG_{}.png".format(timestr)
        print("Captured")
        screenfour.update()

class ScreenFour(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ScreenFour, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        global screenfour
        screenfour = self

    def update(self, *args):
        global filename
        imageWidget = self.ids['imageWid']
        imageWidget.source = filename

screen_manager = ScreenManager()

screen_manager.add_widget(ScreenOne(name="screen_one"))
screen_manager.add_widget(ScreenTwo(name="screen_two"))
screen_manager.add_widget(ScreenThree(name="screen_three"))
screen_manager.add_widget(ScreenFour(name="screen_four"))

class Interface(App):

    def build(self):
        return screen_manager

sample_app = Interface()
sample_app.run()
```

You'd create a `global` variable to save the picture's filename, and then an `Image` widget in your screenfour `Screen`, where you'd update the Image widget's source to the filename of the picture you took. Feel free to contact me if any issues arise

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I checked your code and I had a problem. The application starts and when I press the "Take photo" button, it goes to the next page, and it is completely white. In the application log all the time the same error. I supplemented the question.