# How to make gallery in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, image-gallery

I want to this gallery in kivy [how to make gallery view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14661655/how-to-make-gallery-view) How to add this kivy then is showing many display and carousel in gallery? [How to make an image and display it on the next page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55571906/how-to-make-an-image-and-display-it-on-the-next-page)
Anyone can help this?

```
class Gallery(Screen):
        pass
```

.kv

```
<MyTile@SmartTile>:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: "240dp"
    
<Gallery>
    ScrollView:
        MDGridLayout:
            cols: 3
            row_default_height: (self.width - self.cols*self.spacing[0]) / self.cols
            row_force_default: True
            adaptive_height: True
            padding: dp(4), dp(4)
            spacing: dp(4)
            MyTile:
                source:'*.jpg'
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/loupw.png

Here's got problem..

```
[ WARN:1] global C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-vi271kac\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (376) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::OnReadSample videoio(MSMF): OnReadSample() is called with error status: -1072873821
[ WARN:1] global C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-vi271kac\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (388) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::OnReadSample videoio(MSMF): async ReadSample() call is failed with error status: -1072873821
[INFO   ] [Loader      ] using a thread pool of 2 workers
[ERROR  ] [AsyncImage  ] Not found <*.jpg>
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[ WARN:0] global C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-vi271kac\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (438) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
```

Here's gallery but is not showing any picture in here.. Anyone can tell this code what is problem in codes?

Comment: Try some thing like [this](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/mdswiper/index.html)

Comment: Thanks so much @Neizvestnyj i need this but other than I need make a gallery. for example- Many gridlayout in gallery.

Comment: I am trying use (https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/image-list/) but is not showing any picture in my gallery.

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: @Neizvestnyj where do i post in here? Answer?

Comment: In question, and describe what do you need

Comment: @Neizvestnyj See in my question

Comment: Can you post runnable example

Comment: No! That's empty! No problem! I do post

Comment: It's just easier to understand what you specifically want if the programmer answering your question looks at your attempts to solve this problem. You want to write a full-fledged application for you in your question.

Comment: @Neizvestnyj see in my question. I have post all question in here.

Comment: @Neizvestnyj tell me how to solve in my question?

Comment: Attach an example that I can run (with all the imports as expected) and find out what the error is

Comment: The main problem is my title in **source** and can see error in asyncimage.

Comment: Everything is clearly written in your error, the image you specified does not exist

Comment: Yeah! What is problem in this code only for image. I need one folder in gallery so How do all?

Comment: Everything is correct in your printer, for my project I did about the same, specify the path explicitly. Add images to the layout in a loop

Comment: @Neizvestnyj i have tried to this  (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64643313/generalize-the-kivymd-image-list-example) so it's working then i'm trying to use path `MyTile:
source: r"C:\Users"` it's working too but no showing any picture in that so i want to add source in **MyTitle**  so how do it?

Comment: Tell me everyone! How does all this codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sketched an example of a gallery, I think this is what you want.

```py
from kivymd.app import MDApp

from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

import os

KV = """
<ImageButton@ButtonBehavior+FitImage>

<ImageManager>
    path: ""
    orientation: "vertical"
    size_hint_y: None
    height: root.height
    padding: dp(10)

    ImageButton:
        source: root.path
        
BoxLayout:
    RecycleView:
        id: rv
        key_viewclass: "viewclass"
        RecycleGridLayout:
            padding: dp(2)
            cols: 3
            default_size: None, dp(48)
            default_size_hint: 1, None
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
"""


class ImageManager(BoxLayout):
    pass


class GalleryApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.manager_list = []
        self.dir = os.getcwd()
        self.available_image_format = ['.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.bmp']  # etc

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def on_start(self):
        self.load_images()

    def load_images(self):
        if not self.manager_list:
            for image in os.listdir(self.dir):
                target_filename, target_file_extension = os.path.splitext(image)
                if target_file_extension in self.available_image_format:
                    path_to_image = os.path.join(self.dir, image)
                    self.manager_list.append(
                        {
                            "viewclass": "ImageManager",
                            "path": path_to_image,
                            "height": dp(200),
                        }
                    )
            self.root.ids.rv.data = self.manager_list


GalleryApp().run()
```

Comment: Thanks so much! It's working but isn't looking any picture in this gallery.

Comment: This is logical, the images should be in the same place as the script (in my example this is the case), you can set the path you need using the `self.dir` argument.

Comment: I want to use 'from kivy.properties import StringProperty' in this gallery so how do ?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, just import at the top, and then create the arguments you need in the class itself:
`class Test:
    value = StringProperty()
`

Comment: Thanks A lot! I want this. But A little problem in this gallery because i need also selected button in this gallery [https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/selection/]]  so how do?

Comment: just put it in the `ImageManager` it's the same normal `BoxLayout`

Comment: Read the documentation carefully and look at the examples, you want to put a picture in the list class, this is impossible. I also advise you to study python itself

Comment: I will try it. and thanks for help in my project. :)